# Unable to read complete text file in Python

Tags: python, nltk

I am having a problem reading from a file in Python.

The size of the file I am reading in Python is 90 Mb.  When opened in word, it shows that the total number of words is around 14 million.  But when I read the file in Python, it gives me the length of the file as around 9 million words (8,915,710 words).

When I check to see the last 100 words in the file via the python command

```
print "The length of the Corpus is ", len(tokens), tokens[-100:]
```

I only get words from the around the middle of the original file.

I am using a 64-bit Windows OS and a 32-bit version of Python.

PC specs: i7, 1.8Gz, 6GB RAM

I would like to understand why Python refuses to read beyond 8,915,710 words.

Thanks

CODE:

```
f = open('testtext.txt')
raw = f.read()
corp = lowercase(raw)
tokens = nltk.word_tokenize(corp)
print "The number of words is ", len(tokens), tokens[-100:]
print "corp ", len(corp)
print "raw ", len(raw)
```

I get the following answer:

```
>> The number of words is  8915710
>> corp  53322476
>> raw  53322476
```

Comment: This will be virtually impossible to answer without seeing the [actual  code](http://sscce.org/)

Comment: Is there some practical reason why you need to read the file to memory at once? Why not just run through them line by line, e.g `for line in f: do_smth(line)`

Comment: Can you print the values `len(raw)` and `len(corp)`, also?

Comment: I don't think this will help (that's why it isn't answer), but try `del raw` after the call to `lowercase()`.

Comment: Is it possible that you have a `^Z` in the middle of your file? Can you open your file with a text editor (NOT MS-Word) and examine the location where the reading stops?

Comment: @Rob: What is the ^Z?

Comment: @Robᵩ: Yes, when opened in Notepad++ I can find it, and the last line read in Python is located around the middle of the original text file.

Comment: Can python handle this much data?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Replace this line:

```
f = open('testtext.txt')
```

with this line:

```
f = open('testtext.txt', 'rb')
```

Comment: I did that, and I got a 15205560 words...but now how do I read them from binary to read the last word and check it?

Comment: but why process a file in binary? is there any particular reason?

Comment: Because it has a control-Z in it, which means that it is a binary file, not a text file. What program created the file?

Answer (score 0):

Try processing the file as binary:

```
f = open('file.txt', "rb")
chunkSize = 1024
dataChunk = f.read(chunkSize)
while len(dataChunk):
    processData(dataChunk)
    dataChunk = f.read(chunkSize)
```